# Javascript: How to convert a Map to an Object that has an object as its keys?

Tags: javascript

```js
let johnB = { name: "John Boy" },
    lilyA = { name: "Lily Allen" },
    peterD = { name: "Peter Drucker" };
    
const users = new Map([
  [johnB, 'boudler'], 
  [lilyA, 'rock'],
  [peterD, 'stone']
])

const obj = {};
users.forEach((value, key) => obj[key].name = value)

console.log(obj)
```

The above doesn't work but it shows the basic intent. I want to get name property from the map keys to be the key when the Map is "converted" to an object. Accessing just the key(without .name), javascript stringifies the object so you end up with [object, Object] as the key.

Comment: An object property cannot have an object as the key, it must be a string or a symbol. This is simply not possible. Keep using the `Map`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you just have your logic wrong in your foreach loop.. Is this what you were expecting?

```
{
  "John Boy": "boudler",
  "Lily Allen": "rock",
  "Peter Drucker": "stone"
}
```

```js
let johnB = { name: "John Boy" },
    lilyA = { name: "Lily Allen" },
    peterD = { name: "Peter Drucker" };
    
const users = new Map([
  [johnB, 'boudler'], 
  [lilyA, 'rock'],
  [peterD, 'stone']
])

const obj = {};
users.forEach((value, key) => obj[key.name] = value)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: _"How to convert a Map to an Object that has an object as its keys?"_

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks. As I mentioned in my question, I wanted to use a property as the key in the object, really I guess I meant the value of that property and I had the wrong logic to access the property value.

Answer (score 2):

> …an Object that has an object as its keys?

That does not exist. An object property cannot have an object as the key, it must be a string or a symbol. What are you attempting to achieve is simply not possible. Keep using the `Map` - that's what it is meant to be used for.

Comment: Yes I did mention I knew that an object can not be a key for a property, hence why it stringifies the object, and why Maps are valuable because they do allow for objects to be a key. I do not want the whole object. I want  just the name property from the object, which is a string, to be the key.

Comment: Then use `obj[key.name] = value` instead of `obj[key].name = value`. Also you might want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71878181/edit) to adjust the title